# Storing username password in textfile

Tags: php, authentication

How do I store username and password in a seperate text file instead of this php file.
Below is the code. I wanna make a login registration system without the use of a database.

````
<?php
// Init + Start session
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
session_start();

// Handle AJAX request
switch ($_POST['req']) {
  // Invalid request
  default:
    echo "ERR";
    break;

  // Sign In
  case "in":
    // Already signed in
    if (is_array($_SESSION['user'])) {
      die("OK");
    }

    // Email => Password
    // ADD MORE OF YOUR OWN HERE!
    $users = [
      "john@doe.com" => "123456",
      "jane@doe.com" => "654321"
    ];

    // Check given email & password
    if (isset($users[$_POST['email']]) && $_POST['password'] == $users[$_POST['email']]) {
      $_SESSION['user'] = [
        "email" => $_POST['email']
      ];
      echo "OK";
    } else {
      echo "ERR";
    }
    break;

  // Sign out
  case "out":
    unset ($_SESSION['user']);
    echo "OK";
    break;
}
?>```
````

Comment: save: json_encode -> file_put_contents. get: file_get_contents -> json_decode.. though its bad practice

Comment: or make a string of an array so can do `<?php return [['username' => '', 'password' => '']];` then `include/require` its abit safer (like a config) but still bad practice

Comment: could you guys elaborate how? can you please make sample files?

Comment: i think the answer is you don't.  Why would you store passwords in a text file?  That's exactly what databases are for.  You need credentials to access them, they are independant from the program, they can easily be managed and updated, flagged to need a change or monitor if they have had incorrect guesses etc to help reduce the chances of spamming...

Comment: is just a hint on how to do it, if you want a registration system you need to be able add to the file, which I've already said [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents), and the better/safer way would be to make a php file so going to example.com/users.json won't yield all the usernames and passwords.  also should be stored outside webroot, there is lots of considerations which make it too broad to give you a copy-paste solution over simply using a database. also no one is going to upvote on bad practice, quite the opposite